# ko.observable get updated through a function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, knockout.js

I'm just looking for a quick answer since I am not able to solve it right now.

I want to update an observable depending on the values of different other observables through a function that manipulates the dependent observables.

Let's say I have an object that contains 2 fields. 1 of them is also an object, the 2'nd one being the observable that I want to update.

```
function Control(elem) {
var self = this;
self.element = element;
self.calc = ko.observable();
}
```

Then I have a function that does something considering the *element* and comes up with a value.

```
function Control(elem) {
var self = this;
self.element = element;
self.calc = ko.observable('10');
self.doSomething = function () {
    var dummy = 0;
    if (self.element.number() === 1) 
        dummy = self.element.value + 10;
    else 
        dummy = self.element.value + '+ 10';
    return dummy;
    }
}
```

How can I update the *calc* with the result returned by the function, every time one of the *number* or *value* proprieties of the element changes?

I mention that I don't want to update the *calc* directly by replacing it with *dummy*, because it would make the observable trigger too many times.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/razvangl/cf3kB/

Comment: Do you know about computed observables? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html You write handlers for the `read` and `write` operations and alter whatever else you need inside.

Comment: if you have observable then you can subscribe to the changes it with custom function, check http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables

Comment: @razvan, I noticed that your fiddle does not actually work. There are several errors in it. I haven't worked with Knockout in quite some time, so I forget how to fix your template binding, but the rest should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: Ahh I could help you but that fiddle is so wrong im cba to fix it... :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it. I just made the *calc* a computed observable that equals to the function *doSomething*.

```
function Control(elem) {
var self = this;
self.element = elem;
self.calc = ko.computed(function () {
    var dummy = 0;
    if (self.element.number() === 1) 
        dummy = self.element.value + 10;
    else 
        dummy = self.element.value + '+ 10';
    return dummy;
    });
}
```